# Problem compiling ALSA project's pcm.c sample in raspberry pi zero OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, alsa, c++

I am using a raspberry pi zero W with the latest raspberry pi OS

I have installed both libasound2 and libasound2-dev, and this code that I got off the [raspberry pi forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=15075) for testing the alsa library compiles and runs correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <alsa/pcm.h>

int main() {
  int val;

  printf("ALSA library version: %s\n", SND_LIB_VERSION_STR);

  printf("\nPCM stream types:\n");
  for (val = 0; val <= SND_PCM_STREAM_LAST; val++)
    printf("  %s\n",
      snd_pcm_stream_name((snd_pcm_stream_t)val));

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile the sinewave generation sample code provided in the ALSA project's website here: https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html

This is listed as pcm.c in their examples page

I have saved this code in main.cpp and I have changed `#include "../include/asoundlib.h"` (which causes a file not found error on compile) to `#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>`

I compile this using `gcc main.cpp -o main -lasound -fpermissive`. I get a series of warnings but finally an error at line `for (format = 0; format < SND_PCM_FORMAT_LAST; format++) {` where it says there is `no match for operator++` and the `operand type is 'snd_pcm_format_t' {aka '_snd_pcm_format'})`. But `format` has been declared as `static snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16;` and `snd_pcm_format_t` is an enum [as per their documentation](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gaa14b7f26877a812acbb39811364177f8).

What do I need to do to get this basic example to compile? Or is there a simpler example showing how to generate a sine tone in ALSA using C++, or some blog or tutorial explaining how this sample code by ALSA works?

EDIT: These are the messages seen during build: [error is **main.cpp:842:66: error: no match for ‘operator++’** ]

```
$ gcc main.cpp -o Main -lasound -fpermissive
main.cpp:19:23: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 static char *device = "plughw:0,0";         /* playback device */
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int write_and_poll_loop(snd_pcm_t*, short int*, snd_pcm_channel_area_t*)’:
main.cpp:314:18: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘pollfd*’ [-fpermissive]
     ufds = malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd) * count);
            ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘void async_callback(snd_async_handler_t*)’:
main.cpp:397:77: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘async_private_data*’ [-fpermissive]
 ct async_private_data *data = snd_async_handler_get_callback_private(ahandler);
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp: In function ‘void async_direct_callback(snd_async_handler_t*)’:
main.cpp:469:77: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘async_private_data*’ [-fpermissive]
 ct async_private_data *data = snd_async_handler_get_callback_private(ahandler);
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp: In function ‘void help()’:
main.cpp:756:53: warning: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘snd_pcm_format_t’ {aka ‘_snd_pcm_format’} [-fpermissive]
                 const char *s = snd_pcm_format_name(k);
                                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h:54,
                 from main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/alsa/pcm.h:1065:56: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘const char* snd_pcm_format_name(snd_pcm_format_t)’
 const char *snd_pcm_format_name(const snd_pcm_format_t format);
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:842:27: warning: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘snd_pcm_format_t’ {aka ‘_snd_pcm_format’} [-fpermissive]
             for (format = 0; format < SND_PCM_FORMAT_LAST; format++) {
                           ^
main.cpp:842:66: warning: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’, trying prefix operator instead [-fpermissive]
             for (format = 0; format < SND_PCM_FORMAT_LAST; format++) {
                                                            ~~~~~~^~
main.cpp:842:66: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘snd_pcm_format_t’ {aka ‘_snd_pcm_format’})
main.cpp:903:21: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘short int*’ [-fpermissive]
     samples = malloc((period_size * channels * snd_pcm_format_physical_width(format)) / 8);
               ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:909:19: warning: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘snd_pcm_channel_area_t*’ {aka ‘_snd_pcm_channel_area*’} [-fpermissive]
     areas = calloc(channels, sizeof(snd_pcm_channel_area_t));
             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$
```

Using g++ instead of gcc gives the same error

Comment: You need to show all errors instead of only a subset. Also, when you want to compile C++ code, use `g++` instead of `gcc` (the man page says so, section "Compiling C++ Programs").

Comment: @Wieland added extra information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compile this as a C++ program ("ISO C++ forbids ..."). So you are getting all sorts of warnings because the included headers are C, not C++.

Either rename `main.cpp` to `main.c`, so it gets compiled as a C program, or use the proper C++ way to wrap C-header includes into `extern "C"`, and then use `g++`, and make sure your own code adheres to the C++ standard.